# Is there any way in tabulator to change data format from a file?

Tags: esp32, tabulator

I have a webserver on ESP32 but it generate json data file in following format:

{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138} {"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138}

Basically I also publish above messages via MQTT.

I understand tabulator accept data in following format (notice square brackets at begining and end of file and a comma between 2 messages):

**[**

{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138}**,** {"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138}

**]**

In ESP32 code it is hard to add square brackets at beginning and end of the file as I am appending my messages to file.Is there anything I can do to convert it to compatible format in tabulator before it is applied as input for table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ajaxResponse` option to re-format your data into a Tabulator friendly format.

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/data#ajax-response

I don't believe that your example response from the server is valid JSON.  Your server really should return valid JSON, but if it cannot then you will have to read the response as text and manipulate it into valid JSON.  (If you need help with this, you should ask another question with the `JavaScript` tag.  This part isn't related to Tabulator.)

Here is the first link I found for validating JSON data.
https://jsonlint.com/